# How to add text to image?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rmagick, watermark

I am trying to add text on my image with RMagick. This is my code:

```
version :thumb do
  process :resize_to_limit => [400, 300]
  process :addt
end

def addt
    manipulate! do |img|
      title = Magick::Draw.new
      img = title.annotate(img, 0,0,0,40, 'test') {
          self.font_family = 'Helvetica'
          self.fill = 'white'
          self.stroke = 'transparent'
          self.pointsize = 32
          self.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight
          self.gravity = Magick::CenterGravity
      }

    end
end
```

The problem with this code is that it totally blocks my application. I can't open any other part of my site and can't turn off my server process. I need to kill server process completely to start the application again.

What could be a problem?

Comment: Did you tryed this in a IRB console?

Answer (score 7):

just try this, i cant solve your code . but hope this one can help you with that.

1st install this gem 
**Source:** https://github.com/rmagick/rmagick

next 
To start playing with RMagick, you can stick this in one of your controllers:

```
require ‘RMagick’
include Magick

def addt

img = ImageList.new(‘Your image path eg.public/computer-cat.jpg’)
txt = Draw.new
img.annotate(txt, 0,0,0,0, “The text you want to add in the image”){
txt.gravity = Magick::SouthGravity
txt.pointsize = 25
txt.stroke = ‘#000000′
txt.fill = ‘#ffffff’
txt.font_weight = Magick::BoldWeight
}

img.format = ‘jpeg’
send_data img.to_blob, :stream => ‘false’, :filename => ‘test.jpg’, :type => ‘image/jpeg’,      :disposition => ‘inline’

end
```

hope this one help you..

if you cant understand ..click this http://mikewilliamson.wordpress.com/2010/04/29/adding-text-to-pictures-with-rmagick-and-rails/